# DLL syntax error

Tags: c++, dll, syntax

I'm trying to create a dll with multiple functions, in Visual C++ 2010, and I keep getting a syntax error that is related to using strings, or so it seems.

```
1>c:\users\new\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\getint\getint\getint.h(9): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
```

The code can be seen  below. I literally followed what I did last time; although the last dll I made had 1 function and no boolean or string values.

```
#include <string>

class getInt
{
public:
    //NB :: static __declspec(dllexport) is need to export data from the dll!

    //This declares the function for retrieving an integer value from the user
    static __declspec(dllexport) int toInt (const string &inStr);
    static __declspec(dllexport) int getNum();
    static __declspec(dllexport) bool isValidInt (const string& str);
};
```

There are several other syntax errors but I believe they are arising due to the string being before the other functions.

Comment: `string` is in `std`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `string` class in the global scope, just the one in the `std` namespace. So, change the functions to accept `std::string`s instead.

```
#include <string>

class getInt
{
public:
    //NB :: static __declspec(dllexport) is need to export data from the dll!

    //This declares the function for retrieving an integer value from the user
    static __declspec(dllexport) int toInt (const std::string &inStr);
    static __declspec(dllexport) int getNum();
    static __declspec(dllexport) bool isValidInt (const std::string& str);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` is in the `std` namespace, so prefix with `std::`

```
#include <string>

class getInt
{
public:
    //NB :: static __declspec(dllexport) is need to export data from the dll!

    //This declares the function for retrieving an integer value from the user
    static __declspec(dllexport) int toInt (const std::string &inStr);
    static __declspec(dllexport) int getNum();
    static __declspec(dllexport) bool isValidInt (const std::string& str);
};
```